# Jquery Event onChange for Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I have a page with the following two divs:

```
<div id="searchResults">
</div>

<div class="postSearchOptions" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Is there any way that I can make the "postSearchOptions" div appear when the "searchResults" div is updated by an AJAX call? I don't control the AJAX calls and I want to detect any change in the "searchResults" div.

I tried writing the following JQuery code, but then realized that it requires Jquery 1.4 and I only have 1.3:

```
$("#searchResults").live("change", function() {
    $(".postSearchOptions").css("display", "inline");
});
```

Is there any way to catch the event of the searchResults div changing using either standard JavaScript or Jquery 1.3? Thanks!

Comment: Can you upgrade to jQuery 1.4?

Comment: @SLaks what's in 1.4 that would do something like fire an event when the DOM is updated?  The only thing I know of that provides that is LiveQuery.

Comment: @Pointy: Nothing; I misunderstand the question.  However, he should still upgrade to 1.4; it's faster.

Comment: How would I use LiveQuery to detect the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the onchange event will fire if you are programatically changing the innerHTML. Why don't you just show the Post Search options upon receiving those change i.e. why don't you include it as the last line in your ajax success method.

HTH

Comment: Well, the AJAX methods are shared across the entire website and written in DOJO 0.4 so I was hoping to avoid having to change them. I'll take a peek at them and see if there is a simple way to implement this in the AJAX call. However, I'd prefer a jquery solution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the AJAX calls are made using jQuery, you could call handle the global [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) event and run your code there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use setInterval to watch it, but as others have said it would be nicer to detect the change in the ajax callback. Here's an **sketch** of what a plugin would look like to "watch" a node, like you're trying to do with live:

```
jQuery.fn.watch = function() {
  this.each(function() {
    var original = $(this).html();
    setInterval(function() {
       var newHtml = $(this).html();
       if (newHtml != original) {
         $(this).trigger('change');
         original = newHtml;
       }

    }, 500);

  } );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to working, do....

```
jQuery.fn.watch = function() {
      this.each(function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        var original = $(this).html();
        setInterval(function() {
           var newHtml = $(obj).html();
           if (newHtml != original) {   
            $(obj).trigger('change');
            original = newHtml;
           }

        }, 500);

       } );
}
```