# Add class to element when price content changes JQuery DOMCharacterDataModified

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a class to a price span when the $ value changes. Better visual clue for clients when adding products.

Tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cart-price').bind('DOMCharacterDataModified', function() {
        $('.cart-price').addClass('change');

    var delay = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.cart-price').removeClass('change');
    }, 1100)
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.cart-price.change
{
    color:#F00;
}
```

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9w2gZ/1/

Comment: Can you use `bind` on non-jQuery events?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870059/how-to-determine-when-the-text-of-an-html-element-is-changed)

Comment: use mutation observers - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9w2gZ/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it will be better to use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) because [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#legacy-mutationevent-events) are deprecated. But be aware about [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility) - IE < 11 does not support it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $cartprice = $('.cart-price');

    if ('MutationObserver' in window) {
        var observer = new MutationObserver(highlight);
        observer.observe($cartprice[0], {
            childList: true
        });
    } else {
        //for browsers which does not support MutationObserver
        $cartprice.on('DOMSubtreeModified', highlight)
    }

    function highlight() {
        $cartprice.addClass('change');

        var delay = setTimeout(function () {
            $cartprice.removeClass('change');
        }, 1100)
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9w2gZ/)

Comment: Thanks Arun for your efforts